# CSS3 Transition fires incorrectly on mobile

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a pretty simple menu that I'm working on, and it works wonderfully on desktop, however, when I test it in mobile, going from the home screen to 2 seems to fire all the way to 2.1 (see nav below).

```
<nav id="megamenu">
    <h2>asdasdasdasd 1</h2>
    <h2>asdasdasdasd 2</h2>
    <div>
        <h2>asdasdasdasd 2.1</h2>
        <div>
            <h2>asdasdasdasd 2.1.1</h2>
            <h2>asdasdasdasd 2.1.2</h2>
            <h2>asdasdasdasd 2.1.3</h2>
            <h2>asdasdasdasd 2.1.4</h2>
            <h2>asdasdasdasd 2.1.5</h2>
        </div>

        <h2>asdasdasdasd 2.2</h2>
        <h2>asdasdasdasd 2.3</h2>
        <h2>asdasdasdasd 2.4</h2>
        <h2>asdasdasdasd 2.5</h2>
    </div>

    <h2>asdasdasdasd 3</h2>
    <h2>asdasdasdasd 4</h2>    
    <h2>asdasdasdasd 5</h2>
</nav>​
```

I don't know if it's me not understanding CSS transitions fully, or what. For all of the juicy details, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjjgQ/

Comment: It almost looks like the z-index doesn't kick in until after the animation. Is there a way to get it to fire before the animation with just CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I ended up setting a transition position for the divs instead of left.